# Getting "unexpected token" error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

---

Getting "unexpected token" error in Android Studio? Getting two errors.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
            jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
            jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);
            jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
            jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
            jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());
            answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
            Button solveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);


        solveButton.setOnClickListener( {

                volumeOfOneJellyBean = (3.14159265359 / 6) * (jellybeanfat * jellybeanfat) * (jellybeantall);

                volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace * loadFactor) / volumeOfOneJellyBean;
                int jellyGuess = (int) (volumeofBeans);
                answer.setText("My guess is " + jellyGuess + " Jelly Beans");


    } );   

}
```

}

---

### Getting an error at this end of this line saying "unexpected token"

```
                volumeOfOneJellyBean = (3.14159265359 / 6) * (jellybeanfat * jellybeanfat) * (jellybeantall);
```

---

and this line

---

} );

---

Answer (score 1):

setOnClickListener() method take OnClickListener object as a parameter so create anonymous object of OnClickListener and pass it.

```
  solveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                     // Do your work
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the method View.onCLicklistener as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jellyBeanLength = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.length);
        jellyBeanDiameter = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.diameter);
        jarSizeVolume = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.jarsize);
        jellybeantall = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanLength.getText().toString());
        jellybeanfat = Double.parseDouble(jellyBeanDiameter.getText().toString());
        jellybeanspace = Double.parseDouble(jarSizeVolume.getText().toString());
        answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.answer);
        Button solveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.calculate);


     solveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            volumeOfOneJellyBean = (3.14159265359 / 6) * (jellybeanfat * jellybeanfat) * (jellybeantall);

            volumeofBeans = (jellybeanspace * loadFactor) / volumeOfOneJellyBean;
            int jellyGuess = (int) (volumeofBeans);
            answer.setText("My guess is " + jellyGuess + " Jelly Beans")
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.